# Have an Issue with my list of figures appearance

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, layout

I am working on a big document, therefore I have a lot of figures. The list of figures was perfect until I exceeded 10 figures in one of the chapters. then It started looking like this.

[image: LOF]

Is there a way I can fix the appearance? I am new to Latex so I just didn't know what to do.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you type the following in the preambles:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.6em}}
\makeatother
```

If this answer is not clear, I give you a sample LaTeX program to follow it..

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.6em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Control Systems}
\subsection{Linear Control Systems}
\subsection{Nonlinear Control Systems}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you need to insert figures etc.. Try the commands given in preamble for your document.

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly the way I wanted it

Answer (score 4):

The `tocloft` package is meant for this, and many other aspects of the TOC, LOF and LOT.

```
%\documentclass...
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em} % increase space for figure caption numbers by 2em
%\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2em} % and for table captions if necessary
 ....
\begin{document}
....
```